# Is there a way to insert an ngx breadcrumb dynamically without making a module a child module of some parent?

Tags: angular, xng-breadcrumb

We have a sports booking website where I'd like to be the breadcrumbs as follows:

```
:home/:sport/:city/:court
```

`:home`, `:sport` and `:/city` are all routed to `HomeComponent`. But when a `:court` is supplied, the user should be routed to `CourtComponent`, as you can see in the snippet below:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  
  {
    path: ':city',
    component: HomeComponent,
  },
  {
    path: ':city/:court',
    component: CourtComponent,
  },
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
];
```

This however causes the `:city/:court` path to be treated as a single url, meaning that the user can't click on the `:city` and be routed to `:home/:sport/:city`.

I know I can make `CourtComponent` a child of `HomeComponent`, but adding an extra `router-outlet` and hiding `HomeComponent` when `CourtComponent` is activated seems overcomplicated.

Is there a simpler way to insert a separate `:city` breadcrumb before the `:court` breadcrumb?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!